# RSA encryption using euclidean alorithm

Tags: rsa

when given p=5, q=19, e=5
solution:- 
    n=5*19
     =95
    φ (n)=4*18
         =72

de=1 modφ (n)
d(5)=mod(72)
using euclidean algorithm

72=14(5)+2
5=2(2)+1

back substituition

1=5-2(2)
1=5-2[72-14(5)]
1=15(5)-2(72)

now what how to calculate the value of 'd'

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have already calculated it. If you have 
15(5) - 2*72 = 1 then  15(5) $\equiv 1$ (mod 72).  Can you see the solution now?